# how to get session from codeigniter with node.js

Tags: json, codeigniter, node.js

i'm writing application like social network where in my application can show status update and chat . when i search on internet i found node.js for long polling technology and i think i can use that for chat and streaming page in my application. but when i use node.js i have a stack

this is a technology i want to my project:
1) i'm using codeigniter for framework and mysql database in address localhost:81/myproject
2) and using node.js in port 127.0.0.1:8080 to chat and streaming page

this is code javascript server with node.js name is server.js

```
var sys = require("sys"),
http = require("http"),
url = require("url"),
path = require("path"),
fs = require("fs"),
events = require("events");

function load_static_file(uri, response) {
var filename = path.join(process.cwd(), uri);
path.exists(filename, function(exists) {
    if(!exists) {
        response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write("404 Not Found\n");
        response.end();
        return;
    }

    fs.readFile(filename, "binary", function(err, file) {
        if(err) {
            response.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            response.write(err + "\n");
            response.end();
            return;
        }

        response.writeHead(200);
        response.write(file, "binary");
        response.end();
    });
});
   } 
   var local_client = http.createClient(81, "localhost");

   var local_emitter = new events.EventEmitter();

   function get_users() {
      var request = local_client.request("GET", "/myproject/getUser", {"host": "localhost"});

request.addListener("response", function(response) {
    var body = "";
    response.addListener("data", function(data) {
        body += data;
    });

    response.addListener("end", function() {
        var users = JSON.parse(body);
        if(users.length > 0) {
            local_emitter.emit("users", users);
        }
    });
});

request.end();
 }

 setInterval(get_users, 5000);

 http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    if(uri === "/stream") {

    var listener = local_emitter.addListener("users", function(users) {
        response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type" : "text/plain" });
        response.write(JSON.stringify(users));
        response.end();

        clearTimeout(timeout);
    });

       var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type" : "text/plain" });
        response.write(JSON.stringify([]));
        response.end();

        local_emitter.removeListener(listener);
       }, 10000);

   }
   else {
       load_static_file(uri, response);
   }
  }).listen(8383);

  sys.puts("Server running at http://localhost:8383/");
```

now in codeigniter side i making webservices on url  http://localhost:81/myproject/getUser with response is json format and i access this with session auhtentication if not is redirect to login page.

```
[{"user_id":"2a20f5b923ffaea7927303449b8e76daee7b9b771316488679","token":"3m5biVJMjkCNDk79pGSo","username":"rakhacs","password":"*******","name_first":"rakha","name_middle":"","name_last":"cs","email_id":"email@gmail.com","picture":"img\/default.png","active":"1","online":"0","created_at":"2011-09-20 11:14:43","access":"2","identifier":"ae70c3b56df19a303a7693cdc265f743af5b0a6e"},{"user_id":"9a6e55977e906873830018d95c31d2bf664c2f211316493932","token":"RoUvvPyVt7bGaFhiMVmj","username":"ferdian","password":"*****","name_first":"willy","name_middle":"","name_last":";f;w","email_id":"email1@gmail.com","picture":"img\/default.png","active":"1","online":"0","created_at":"2011-09-20 11:47:20","access":"2","identifier":"1ccd4193fa6b56b96b3889e59c5205cc531177c9"}]
```

this is the point problem when i execute `node server.js`
i get error like this `undefined:0
sysntaxerror:unexpected end of input
at object.parse(native)`

i don't know about that error  i think because i using session ? but i'm not sure.
when i test using  test.js for testing my webservices

```
var http = require("http")
var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 81,
    path: '/myproject/getUser',
    method: 'GET'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
   });
});
req.on('error', function(e) {
   console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});
// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

and this is the output

`problem with request: parse error`

but when i using another webservice who has been response json format too and not using session that's work i can get the body response..if this problem is session how i can fix this?..this is can make me confused..thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hard to say but I would primary try to send an object in jSON and not directly an array. i.e. just encapsulate the array into an object:

```
{"data":[…]}
```

This "may" be causing the parse error.

Something else, for this purpose, it won't be bad to add the following to your responding PHP method:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: i think in my json is no problem .because i can parse that.i try your suggestion to add header cache-control,expires,and content-type.but when i'm executing "node test.js" that is same error...and when i check the header response i found redirect location to login page..

Comment: The array itself is syntactically correct however I already got exactly the same problem as yours while returning an array instead of an object, I then had to encapsulate it as I proposed to do so above.

Comment: As you get a parse error you should double check what is parsed for real. Try to console.log the answer. If you cannot do it because the data got is too obfuscated (you only get the error and cannot access to the object itself) I would suggest to use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and look what really happened in your request. Maybe your "path" is simply wrong and you are trying to parse an "Error 404 result page" -> Is your relative path really coherent with the Node.j VS codeigniter's folder ? Try replacing it with an absolute path.